# Access object within an array within an array

Tags: php, zabbix

My API call gave me the following code:

```
Array ( [ABC01] => 
       Array ( [0] => 
              stdClass Object ( 
                   [hostid] => 12345 
                   [location_lat] => 40 
                   [location_lon] => 70 
                   [site_address_a] => Hello World Blvd 
                   [site_address_b] => Foo 100 
                   [site_city] => Redmond
                   [site_state] => Washington
                   [site_country] => USA ) )
```

Ultimately, I'm trying to get this:

```
Array ( [ABC01] =>  
                   [hostid] => 12345 
                   [location_lat] => 40 
                   [location_lon] => 70 
                   [site_address_a] => Hello World Blvd 
                   [site_address_b] => Foo 100 
                   [site_city] => Redmond
                   [site_state] => Washington
                   [site_country] => USA ) )
```

I have nearly three foreach loops and I'm still a bit lost. I know there must be an easy way but I'm not too familiar with PHP. I just used get_object_vars to get ahold of the location object:

```
 foreach($getLocations as $key => $value) {
    print_r(get_object_vars($value[0]));
}
```

Am I on the right track? I then get confused how to tie this back to the host name (ABC01) since that is what I want to output, not the hostid. Thanks for your help, this PHP noob appreciates it.

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you want to output and if there is always only one hostname and inside that only one element 0, not more.

Answer (score 1):

If the output you want is actually this:

```php
array(1) {
  ["ABC01"]=>
  array(8) {
    ["hostid"]=>
    int(12345)
    ["location_lat"]=>
    int(40)
    ["location_lon"]=>
    int(70)
    ["site_address_a"]=>
    string(16) "Hello World Blvd"
    ["site_address_b"]=>
    string(7) "Foo 100"
    ["site_city"]=>
    string(7) "Redmond"
    ["site_state"]=>
    string(10) "Washington"
    ["site_country"]=>
    string(3) "USA"
  }
}
```

Then yes I think you're on the right track, this should produce it:

```php
$output = [];
foreach($data as $key => $value) {
    $output[$key] = get_object_vars($value[0]);
}
var_dump($output);
```

Note that this assumes a single '0' element for each host name.

> I then get confused how to tie this back to the host name (ABC01)
>   since that is what I want to output, not the hostid

The host name is the $key in the foreach, it's used to specify the key of the output array.